# adding Foreground converter to DatagridTextColumn in xaml

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid, f#

I'm trying to add a converter to a DataGridTextColumn to convert the foreground brush based on the value of the cell in the xaml file.  The DecimalConverter works fine and follows the same pattern.

Here is my xaml...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <y:FixedDecimalConverter x:Key="FixedDecimalConverter" />
    <y:ForegroundValueConverter x:Key="ForegroundValueConverter" />       
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<data:DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="Absolute Return" 
    Binding="{Binding totalAbsoluteReturn.value, Converter={StaticResource FixedDecimalConverter}}"  
    Foreground="{Binding totalAbsoluteReturn.value, Converter={StaticResource ForegroundValueConverter}}" />
```

Here is the converter...

```
type ForegroundValueConverter() =
    interface  IValueConverter with
        member this.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture) = 
             let o: obj = upcast new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
             o

        member this.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture) = raise <| NotImplementedException()
```

...

Here is the error message

> Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight Application  Code: 4004
>   Category: ManagedRuntimeError
>   Message:
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:
>   AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line:
>   29 Position: 32]    at
>   System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator)    at
>   Module1.MyIdeas..ctor()    at
>   Module1.Template..ctor()    at
>   Module1.MyApp..ctor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it, but the folks oer there claim it works

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/151524/338879.aspx#338879